# Error on creating spiral arms for galaxy formation on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, galaxy, spiral

i have writing this code but in my code there is error, how can i make spiral arms from this code by used profile used below i want to create surface density profile using spiral arms of the galaxy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import*
#r,theta = meshgrid(np.arange(0,200,1), np.arange(0,360,1))

t = 1
c = 100
alpha = 12 #degree
m = 2
rd = 5
sigd = 35
omegap = 8.4
r,theta = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,200,1), np.arange(1,360,1))
def k(m,r):
    k1 = (m/r)*(1/0.212)
    #print(k1)
    return k1
def sig0(sigd,r,rd):
    sig_0 = sigd*np.exp(-r/rd)
    return sig_0
def phi (m,r):
    phi_1 = m*(1/0.212)*np.log(r)
    return phi_1
def omega (r):
    omega_1 = (200/r)+1.37
    return omega_1
def kappa (r):
    kppa= (400*sqrt(0.5))/r
    return kppa
def xt(c,m,r):
    x_t = ((k(m,r)**2)*(c**2))/((kappa(r))**2)
    return x_t
def v(m,omegap,r):
    v_1 = (m/kappa(r))*(omegap-omega(r))
    return v_1
def del_12 (c,r,m,omegap):
    de1 = (1-((4*xt(c,m,r))*((1-v(m,omegap,r)**2))))**(1/2)
    return de1

def sig(r,m,t,theta,c,sigd,rd,omegap):
    r,theta = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,200,1), np.arange(1,360,1))

    sig1 = sig0(sigd,r,rd)+(((abs(k(m,r)))/r**(1/2))*(1/(abs(del_12(c,m,r,omegap))**(1/2)))*(np.cos(omegap*m*t-m*theta+phi(m,r))))
    #+ ((abs(k(m,r)))/r**(1/2))*(1/abs(del_12(c,r,m,omegap))**(1/2))*np.cos(omegap*m*t-m*theta+phi)
    return sig1

model = sig(r,m,t,theta,c,sigd,rd,omegap)
print(model)
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(model)
#plt.contour(x,y,galaxy_model_1)
#pf.writeto('gal_1.fits', galaxy_model_1,  clobber=1)  
#ax2=fig.add_subplot(122, axisbg='white')
#ax2.imshow((abs(galaxy_model_2))**0.2)
plt.show()
```

more information about this code is given by this reference
Contribution of spiral arms to the surface brightness distribution
of disk galaxies
http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1997A%26A...318..741S